# Python: multiprocessing - improving function time 6x didn't impact the performance of the loop

Tags: python-2.7

someone?
I have a function:

```
    def _process_sensor(self, last_value, raw_data, raw_string, tariff_data, counter, electricity):
        raw_data = OrderedDict(sorted(raw_data.items(), key=lambda t: iso8601.parse_date(t[0])))
        interval_data = self._transform_cumulative_to_interval(last_value, raw_data, electricity)
        interval_data = self._calculate_sensor_commodities(interval_data, tariff_data, tariff_data['ID'], electricity)
        self._persist_results(raw_string, interval_data, tariff_data['ID'], electricity)
```

And yesterday each function execution took 2s, today I improved it to take around 0.25s and I am very happy about that but when I call my function:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

pool = Pool(processes=8)

for sensor_id in today_values:
    try:
        pool.apply(self._process_sensor, (yesterday_values[sensor_id], today_values[sensor_id],
                                                  raw_string[sensor_id], self.electricity_tariff_data[sensor_id],
                                                  processed, True, ))
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.warning('Some data error: {}'.format(e))
    processed += 1
```

Looping through 100 elements takes the same amount of time: about 24 seconds. What can I be doing wrong? Parameters passed are parts of dictionaries. self._persist_results calls AWS from s3transfer.manager import TransferManager.

Edit: I know I have an 8 core box I'm running the code on. And did a pool.apply_async with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def _looop(dict_obj):
    _process_sensor(**dict_obj)

to_process = []
for sensor_id in today_values:
    to_process.append(copy.deepcopy({'fields': True,
                         'for': True,
                         '_process_sensor': True}))
pool.map_async(_looop, to_process)
```

Didn't have time to check if copy.deepcopy is necessary (and to be honest I don't need to put it in a separate loop - I will refactor that soon).

Answer (score 0):

If a single run takes 0.25s and 100 take 24s, it sounds like the function is running into contention, so that most of its run time isn't executing in parallel.  This is quite common when there's contention around I/O resources, so my guess would be that `_persist_results` call is the culprit.

Looking into `TransferManager`, it seems there's a `max_concurrency` setting on the `[TransferConfig][1]` - looks like that should default to 10, any chance you've reduced that?  I'd suggest checking if that's being set, and if not, see if setting it explicitly helps.